# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected permute_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 4)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning

I have been debugging this error for the past week and I'm not sure why my code is not working.

We have a custom environment and our reinforcement learning problem is taking a 512x512 image and deciding if we should do action 1 or action 2.

```
env = customEnv()
nb_actions = env.action_space.n # 2 options
shape = env.observation_space.shape
pool_size = 2

input_shape = (512, 512, 1) # 1 channel, grayscale image
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, padding="same", input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(pool_size, pool_size)))

model.add(Convolution2D(64, 2, padding="same")) 
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(pool_size, pool_size)))

model.add(Convolution2D(64, 2, padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(pool_size, pool_size)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(nb_actions))
model.add(Activation('linear'))
print(model.summary())

memory = SequentialMemory(limit=1000000, window_length=WINDOW_LENGTH)
policy = BoltzmannQPolicy()
dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, nb_actions=nb_actions, policy=policy, memory=memory,
               nb_steps_warmup=50000, gamma=.99, target_model_update=10000,
               train_interval=4, delta_clip=1.)
dqn.compile(Adam(learning_rate=.00025), metrics=['mae'])

dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=50000, visualize=False, verbose=2)

dqn.save_weights(f'dqn_CTEnv_weights.h5f', overwrite=True)

dqn.test(env, nb_episodes=5, visualize=False)
```

Full error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DQN_CT.py", line 60, in <module>
    dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=50000, visualize=False, verbose=2)
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rl/core.py", line 168, in fit
    action = self.forward(observation)
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rl/agents/dqn.py", line 224, in forward
    q_values = self.compute_q_values(state)
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rl/agents/dqn.py", line 68, in compute_q_values
    q_values = self.compute_batch_q_values([state]).flatten()
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rl/agents/dqn.py", line 63, in compute_batch_q_values
    q_values = self.model.predict_on_batch(batch)
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_v1.py", line 1201, in predict_on_batch
    x, extract_tensors_from_dataset=True)
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_v1.py", line 2334, in _standardize_user_data
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_v1.py", line 2361, in _standardize_tensors
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 574, in standardize_input_data
    'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected permute_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 4)
```

I have looked at a lot of other posts regarding this error and most seems to point out that the input shape needs to be 3D (width, height, channel) which doesn't seem to be working for us. We also tried (batch size (window_length), width, height, channel), but doing so gives us another error `ValueError: Input 0 of layer permute is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5. Full shape received: [None, 4, 512, 512, 1]`

Any help on this problem would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Tried your model architecture with different dataset with little modifications .

**Working sample code**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

import pathlib
dataset_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('flower_photos', origin=dataset_url, untar=True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)
batch_size = 32
img_height = 512
img_width = 512

train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

for image_batch, labels_batch in train_ds:
  print(image_batch.shape)
  print(labels_batch.shape)
  break

input_shape = (180, 180, 3) # 3 channel, RGB image
model = Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation= 'relu',padding="same", input_shape=input_shape))
#model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D())

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 2, activation= 'relu',padding="same")) 

model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D())

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 2, activation= 'relu',padding="same"))
#model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D())

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64,activation= 'relu'))
#model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32,activation= 'linear'))
#model.add(Activation('linear'))
print(model.summary())
```

**Output**

```
Model: "sequential_3"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv2d_7 (Conv2D)           (None, 180, 180, 32)      896       
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_6 (MaxPooling  (None, 90, 90, 32)       0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 conv2d_8 (Conv2D)           (None, 90, 90, 64)        8256      
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_7 (MaxPooling  (None, 45, 45, 64)       0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 conv2d_9 (Conv2D)           (None, 45, 45, 64)        16448     
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_8 (MaxPooling  (None, 22, 22, 64)       0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 flatten_2 (Flatten)         (None, 30976)             0         
                                                                 
 dense_4 (Dense)             (None, 64)                1982528   
                                                                 
 dense_5 (Dense)             (None, 32)                2080      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 2,010,208
Trainable params: 2,010,208
Non-trainable params: 0
```